# Drop or Discard in Mansion of Madness?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

One of the mythos cards in the game says that the investigator is out of ammo and that she needs to discard her weapon. Would you interpret this as the card should be removed from the game as oppossed to the cards that says the investigator needs to drop the item, ie. in the current room.

I would have said remove the card if it wasn't for that the investigators have an action called "discard" where they actually drop the items in the current room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret that card as "Discard means **discard**. Place in the discard pile."

The **action** is something that players can do to leave equipment cached for each other.

The **mythos card** is an act of aggression carried out by the Keeper. It probably costs Threat. There is also **zero** support in the fiction for a weapon becoming reloaded by being dropped.

**EDIT**: OK. So, I played *Mansions* last night for the first time in a while, and came up with this card. It's clearly **Discard** on the Mythos card and **Drop** in the Investigator action list. There's no confusion here at all, no interpretation necessary.

Comment: Seems a bit harsh in relation to the cost for the keeper on the other hand weapons are a real pain for the keeper :) I believe you are right though

Comment: Yep, you discard the weapon.